# Playwright JAVA: How to get the VALUE of an input field

Tags: java, playwright, webautomation, playwright-java

Hello Playwright experts,

I have this input field

```
<input id="myName" placeholder="e.g. Max" maxlength="15" class="xyz"/>
```

I have tried this JAVA code:

```
page.locator("[placeholder=\"e.g. Max\"]").textContent();
```

It does not work :-( but I can fill

```
page.locator("[placeholder=\"e.g. Max\"]").fill("Loren"); // this works
```

Could you help and has an idea?

Thank you in advance.

*Cheers*
Loren

Answer (score 6):

`textContext` won't return a value of an input. The same will happen if you try that in the DevTools.
You can use [inputValue](https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-input-value) instead.
e.g.

```
page.locator("#myName").inputValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to assert your value you can use the `.hasValue` assertion. You can read more about it from the [playwright docs](https://playwright.dev/java/docs/test-assertions#locator-assertions-to-have-value).

```java
assertThat(page.locator("#myName")).hasValue("input-value");
```

Comment: wowww, so many possibilities to this issue. :-) Thank you very much. I have learnt something new :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the imho more generic `getAttribute`:

```
page.locator("#myName").getAttribute("placeholder");
```

Documentation: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-get-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Theory is that

inputValue() is used to retrieve the value of input elements that you just typed.

textContent() is a method that is used to get the visible text content of an element on a web page. it can be a header tag. This method is useful for web scraping and verifying the content of a page.

Here is a code example

```
page.navigate("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/forgot_password");
Locator inputTextField=page.locator("//input[@id='email']");


// Get input text of an element using inputValue();
String actualInputVal=inputTextField.inputValue();
System.out.println("actualInputVal=="+actualInputVal);
// Assert the value of it using  hasValue
assertThat(inputTextField).hasValue("My input");


Locator forgetPasswordHeader=page.locator("//h2[text()='Forgot Password']");
String forgetPasswordHeaderActualText=forgetPasswordHeader.textContent();
System.out.println("forgetPasswordHeaderActualText=="+forgetPasswordHeaderActualText);
// you can't use hasValue here since  it's not an input element so use hasText
assertThat(forgetPasswordHeader).hasText("Forgot Password");
```

This will print

```
actualInputVal==My input
forgetPasswordHeaderActualText==Forgot Password
```